# Write down $n$ - tuple as a set

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, elementary-set-theory

hello can you help me with that?

Let an $n$-tuple be defined as

$$ (a_1 , a_2 , \dots , a_n) = (( a_1 , a_2 , \dots , a_{n-1}),a_n) $$

write down $n$-tuple $ (a_1 , a_2 , \dots , a_n)$ as a set

I know that if we have $ (a_1,a_2,a_3) $ I can write it like this
$$  \{ \{a_1,a_2\}\{a_3\}\} = \{\{a_1,a_2\}\{ a_1,a_2,a_3 \}\} = \{ \{a_1\}\{a_1,a_2\}\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}\}    $$
and what i should do for $n$- tuple?

Comment: See [tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple#Definitions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**  Start with a pair $(a,b):=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$, which is Kuratowski's now accepted definition.  Then generalize via the point of view that $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)=(a,b)$, with $a=(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}),b=x_n$, as you indicated.

So $(x_1,x_2,x_3)=((x_1,x_2),x_3)=\{\{(x_1,x_2)\},\{(x_1,x_2),x_3\}\}=\{\{\{x_1\},\{x_1,x_2\}\},\{\{\{x_1\},\{x_1,x_2\}\},x_3\}\}$.